# Mainframe access for test automation through Java code

Tags: java, mainframe

Is there any way, we can connect mainframe through java code and can see the screen content in console. Also we can send the option as input and go further in mainframe screens. I need this basically for test automation purpose.

Comment: Probably. Depends on *what* mainframe.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Comment: Hey @FedericoklezCulloca, i am not sure about what mainframe, as i have recently started to look into it. But, i am connecting to a host through teamtalk.2000 and navigating to few screens. I will try to get some more information about this. Right now i know its mainframe IBM 3270 emulation as showing in teamtalk.

Comment: This would not be a function of the _mainframe_, but a function of your 3270 emulator.  It's called screen scraping; many 3270 emulators provide a mechanism to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Robot framework but I believe it will do what you want.  Its not Java but uses Python; should fit the bill based on you question.

https://github.com/Altran-PT-GDC/Robot-Framework-Mainframe-3270-Library

Answer (score 0):

Rational Functional Tester with its "Extension for Terminal-based Applications" will do this quite well. See here for more information:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJMXE_10.0.1/com.ibm.test.terminal.docs/topics/cxmlrft0001.html

You can use its Java APIs (called the Host Access Class Library, or HACL for short) if you want to do anything particularly fancy, but "out of the box" it's a full test automation suite for terminal-based user interfaces. (Terminal-based UIs are available in a variety of systems, including but not only mainframes. Apple's macOS offers a terminal-based UI, for example. Mainframes provide a variety of UIs, including, but not only, classic terminal-based UIs. RFT's Extension for Terminal-based Applications is able to test practically every terminal-based UI across all systems that offer them.)